# Communicating to COM port with pyserial, but device not interpreting command corectly

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to communicate to a device through COM port. It works well with PuTTY but I can't seem to properly send the commands through either python (using pyserial) or through the arduino IDE (using the serial monitor). Ultimately I need to use this with python but I am testing all options. When I log the communication with putty, it interprets "time" as "[1@t[1@i[1@m[1@e", so I am not sure if this is a particular type of encoding. In python, I've tried sending the command exactly like that, as well as in ascii (which results in an error as expected) and encoding it in bytes, but nothing seems to be working. Below if the full PuTTY log:

```
wrc# [1@t[1@i[1@m[1@e 
Thu, Jan 1, 1970, 00:42:58 +686139584 nanoseconds. 
wrc# [1@t[1@e[1@m[1@p 
pcb:41.1250 
wrc#
```

I have also tried adding the wrc# to the message but again, it doesn't work. If it's any help, the baudrate is 115200.

EDIT: Uploading the python code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=0.1)
ser.write(str.encode('time'))
ser.readlines()
```

returns:

```
[]
```

The 'time' command should return what you see in the second line of the PuTTY log, but it returns nothing. The code above is what I have used multiple times in other serial devices and it's worked well in the past.

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be issues, but without seeing your code it is difficult to provide any help. Please post your python code using pyserial and if this is trying to communicate to an Arduino it might be helpful to see the arduino code as well.

Comment: I added the Python code. I am not using an arduino, I just usually pull up the serial monitor to quickly test commands on serial devices.

Comment: My first thought is that your device is not responding, but since it works with Putty my next thought would be that you are calling `ser.readlines()` before the device has time to respond. You could increase your timeout to give your device more time to respond.

Comment: I tried with timeout=5 but unfortunately same response. I also just tried explicitly passing the arguments for stopbits, parity, bytesize, etc. but same.

Comment: Without knowing the device I don't know that I can give any specific advice. Just standard debugging from here. If possible verify that the device actually receives a message (maybe a flashing rx led). If it receives, but doesn't respond then your packet is probably wrong (encoding, maybe missing \n).

Comment: Actually, depending on the device and how it parses the stream from the serial port it may be looking for a specific delimiter between commands/packets like a carriage return or newline. I can't say whether that is included by putty or not, but you don't have that in your python code. You can try adding \r, \n, or \r\n to your command.